# cancancan load_and_authorize_resource NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan, cancancan

I use the CanCanCan, Devise and Rolify gem to for authentication and permission management. But when I create a new controller I got this message:

```
NameError in PanelController#dashboard
uninitialized constant Panel
```

My PanelController:

```
class PanelController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def dashboard
  end
end
```

When I remove this line: `load_and_authorize_resource`
the Route works. But I can access it without authentication. Do I need a PanelModel to use it?

My AbilityModel is this:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    alias_action :create, :read, :update, :destroy, :to => :crud

    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    elsif user.has_role? :user
      can [:read], User
      can [:update, :edit], User do |account|
        account.email == user.email
      end
    else
      # can :read, :all
      can [:create, :new], User
    end
  end
end
```

Yesterday my Code works great but today I don't know why I get this error. 
Maybe anyone can help me.

My Routes are this for the Controller:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    authenticated :user do
      # Rails 4 users must specify the 'as' option to give it a unique name
      root :to => "panels#dashboard", :as => :panel
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end
  end
```

Comment: Yes, load_and_authorize_resource is looking for the Panel model.

Comment: But why? How I can use it without it tries to look for the PanelModel but with authentication?

Comment: How are you going to check permissions for the dashboard action in your Ability class without the Panel model?

Comment: can I check it with the routes.rb?

Comment: You can, but than why do you need another check using CanCanCan?

Comment: I not sure. I was thinking with `load_and_authorize_resource` I can check if the user has rights to view this page. Without using a model

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use CanCanCan without a corresponding model using `authorize_resource :class => false` like this

```
class PanelController < ApplicationController
  authorize_resource :class => false

  def dashboard
  end
end
```

and then in your ability:

```
elsif user.has_role? :user
  can :dashboard, :panel
```